# Can a javascript object containing xml data be parsed using the jquery .ajax() call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object containing the xml data in that. I want to parse this object inside the .ajax() call in the jquery. Does anyone know how to do it? I am struggling for the pointer. Please help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post what you have so far?

Comment: Hi, I am not able to start. What I have done so far was with .xml file. Now instead of .xml file, I need to start with an object. Can I do that?

Comment: [Google does.](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery)

Comment: @moonwave99: This is what I have done until now. But in this case, instead of  url: "jquery_xml.xml", say the object xmlObj contains the xml data which is stored in file jquery_xml.xml. Now i want the source to be xmlObj and not the url file. The reason for doing so is, I wont make any calls to server again, everything would happen on browser side.

Comment: when you parse the first round of xml, it typically doesn't take much additional code to store results into a javascript object literal or array either. Samples of xml would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jQuery.parseXML( data );`

See docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of parsing a catalog of books contained in `book` tags and caching results into a javascript object for much easier access to data later on. XML Sample taken from [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This allows a lot easier data access later in than having to parse the xml again to look for results. The format of the store object can be set to best suit needs of the app this way also.

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/WpFUE/

```
var xmlResults = {};

$(xml).find('book').each(function() {
    var $book = $(this);
    var id = $book.attr('id');
    var title = $book.find('title').text();
    var auth = $book.find('author').text();
    var descrip = $book.find('description').text();
    /* store data in object with id for key */
    xmlResults[id] = {
        author: auth
    }

    $('body').append('<div class="book_wrap" data-id="' + id + '">Book: ' + title + '<br>' + descrip + '<p>CLICK ANYEHWERE ON DIV TO GET AUTHOR</div>')

})

$('.book_wrap').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    /* no parsing of xml, use simple javascript object notation to referece data stored*/
    var auth = xmlResults[id].author;
    alert('Author is '+auth)
})
```